# Why does my tornadoFX ObservableList not receive updates?

Tags: kotlin, tornadofx

I have a simple tornadoFX program that generates some circles in random locations on the screen. However, none of the circles get drawn. I've added some debug code to print a line when a circle is drawn, and it only prints once.

I would expect circles to appear at 100ms intervals, as well as when I click the "Add actor" button.

```
private const val WINDOW_HEIGHT = 600
private const val WINDOW_WIDTH = 1024

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    Application.launch(MainApp::class.java, *args)
}

class MainApp : App(WorldView::class, Stylesheet::class)

data class Actor(val x: Double, val y: Double)

class WorldView: View("Actor Simulator") {
    override val root = VBox()
    private val actors = ArrayList<Actor>(0)

    init {
        tornadofx.runAsync {
            (0..100).forEach {
                val x = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble(0.0, WINDOW_WIDTH.toDouble())
                val y = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble(0.0, WINDOW_HEIGHT.toDouble())
                actors.add(Actor(x, y))
                Thread.sleep(100)
            }
        }
    }

    init {
        with(root) {
            stackpane {
                group {
                    bindChildren(actors.observable()) {
                        circle {
                            centerX = it.x
                            centerY = it.y
                            radius = 10.0
                            also {
                                println("drew circle")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                button("Add actor") {
                    action {
                        actors.add(Actor(0.0, 0.0))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Oddly, if I put a breakpoint during the circle draw code, circles will draw and the debug line will print.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some observations:

1. Calling `someList.observable()` will create an observable list backed by the underlying list, but mutations on the underlying list will not emit events. You should instead initialize `actors` as an observable list right away.
2. Access to an observable list must happen on the UI thread, so you need to wrap mutation calls in `runLater`.
3. For people trying to run your example - you didn't include a stylesheet, but references one in your `App` subclass, so the IDEA will most probably import the TornadoFX `Stylesheet` class. This will not end well :)
4. The `also` call has no effect, so I removed it.
5. I updated your code to best practices here and there, for example with regards to how to create the root node :)

Updated example taking these points into account looks like this:

```
private const val WINDOW_HEIGHT = 600.0
private const val WINDOW_WIDTH = 1024.0

class MainApp : App(WorldView::class)

data class Actor(val x: Double, val y: Double)

class WorldView : View("Actor Simulator") {

    private val actors = FXCollections.observableArrayList<Actor>()

    override fun onDock() {
        runAsync {
            (0..100).forEach {
                val x = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble(0.0, WINDOW_WIDTH.toDouble())
                val y = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble(0.0, WINDOW_HEIGHT.toDouble())
                runLater {
                    actors.add(Actor(x, y))
                }
                Thread.sleep(100)
            }
        }
    }

    override val root = stackpane {
        setPrefSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT)
        group {
            bindChildren(actors) {
                circle {
                    centerX = it.x
                    centerY = it.y
                    radius = 10.0
                    println("drew circle")
                }
            }
        }
        button("Add actor") {
            action {
                actors.add(Actor(0.0, 0.0))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer is great! But it makes me wonder... There is very little search results for `bindChildren` and yet it feels like a totally core functionality. Pretty much when the default table or listviews are not sufficient and I want some fancy rendering for each item, there is no other choice but use `bindChildren`. Or is there another way?